# Stop currently executing scripts in chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to programatically inject js into a tab using chrome.tabs.executeScript when the user clicks the extension button. But the problem I'm facing is if I press the extension button n times, the code gets injected n times and hence any action, such as opening a new tab in that script gets executed n times and n new tabs are open when that action is performed in the script. Is there a way to prevent code from getting injected multiple times in the same tab. Or is there any way to stop the currently executing script in a chrome tab so that I can stop that script and re-inject it again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is difficult to stop the running script forcibly. Instead, you should prevent the multiple registrations of the content script. For example, it can communicate between the page which the button has and the content script with [chrome.runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) API. That is, you can implement code like the follows:

1. (Page) When the click event received, disable the button.
2. (Page) Inject your content script against some tab.
3. (Content Script) When all tasks done in the content script, the content script sends some message.
4. (Page) When the message received, enable the button.